# ASP VB print direct

Tags: printing, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a web program with 14 different modules each which produces a reports in the range of 1 to 5 pages. I now have one page where the user can go to chose which report(s) he/she wishes to print out. I can easily produce the correct multi-module report on the screen and then ask the user to use their browsers Print command. That works, but scrolling 30-50 pages on the screen is not the optimal solution. Does anyone know of a way to print directly to the printer or a PDF file. Understand this is a website so I will not know the browser, operating system equipment, etc. Thanks. Rick

Comment: If you want to generate a PDF then you need to install a third party component, like ASP.PDF or ABCpdf.
http://www.asppdf.com/download.html
http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you do a window.print in a client javascript or vbscript all pages of the document should be printed. You will get the default print-dialog first though.
Here an example.

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script>
 function printpage()
   {
   window.print()
   }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<input type="button" value="Print this page" onclick="printpage()">

</body>
</html>
```

In some cases, eg a grid generated from javascriptframework like ExtJs you will only get the visible part of the grid. In such a case i usually also give the user a button to export the data to Excel or Word if it is more text-like. There he can adjust layout- and printsettings. If you are interested i can publish such a routine for a ExtJs grid.